# Going to horoscope pages and channels in order to refute them

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, interfaith

What is the ruling on going to horoscope Facebook pages and channels on YouTube in order to refute them only, because this is shirk and based on myths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is the practice of astrology is **`haram`**, but also visiting an astrologer and listening to his predictions, buying books on astrology or reading one's horoscope are also **`forbidden`**. Since astrology is mainly used to predicting the future, those who practice it are considered fortune-tellers.

```
"The salah (daily prayer) of whoever approaches a fortune-teller and asks him about anything will not be accepted for forty days and nights."
Sahih Muslim, vol. 4, p. 1211, no. 5440
```

Following horoscopes or things like that is haram but to read about them is forbidden not you can say haram as well as i found out but here you can read more:

https://sunnahonline.com/library/beliefs-and-methodology/70-the-islamic-ruling-on-horoscopes

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care?  There are so many other better causes in life that need attention, why focus on something unimportant and one which you cannot prove.  Say, for example, it says 'Today all women Capricorn are going to have a great day and hear some good news".  Now, prove that statement to be wrong?  You cannot as it's so generic and meaningless.

If you want an excuse to read them yourself, then know that Allah knows what's in everyones hearts.  There are worse things you can do than read horoscope pages daily.  To read it is not Haram, to believe in it is.